# compiled class problem in java try/catch block

Tags: java

I have try and catch block in JAVA code

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class TryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String zipPath ="D:/test";
        try (ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipPath))){
            String Hello ="Hello";
            System.out.println("==============>"+Hello);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

And my compiled class look like

/*
 * Decompiled with CFR 0.145.
 */
....

```
try {
    try (ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(string));){
        String string2 = "Hello";
        System.out.println("==============>" + string2);
    }
```

....

I wounder why another try block added in compile time.

Full Source code in

https://github.com/vikram06/java_try_catch_bug

Comment: You don't actually have `catch`

Comment: @Guy you can see the whole code at github. I didn't get the problem.

Comment: Can you explain please?

Comment: @Z3RP [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Guy everything you need is at his example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is explained in the JLS [14.20.3.2 Extended try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.2) :

> The meaning of an extended try-with-resources statement:

```
try ResourceSpecification
    Block
Catchesopt
Finallyopt
```

> is given by the following translation to a basic try-with-resources
>   statement (§14.20.3.1) nested inside a try-catch or try-finally or
>   try-catch-finally statement:

```
try {
    try ResourceSpecification
        Block
}
Catchesopt
Finallyopt
```

> The effect of the translation is to put the ResourceSpecification
>   "inside" the try statement. This allows a catch clause of an extended
>   try-with-resources statement to catch an exception due to the
>   automatic initialization or closing of any resource.
>
> Furthermore, all resources will have been closed (or attempted to be
>   closed) by the time the finally block is executed, in keeping with the
>   intent of the finally keyword.

Answer (score 4):

When you're using try with resources (I mean `try (...) {...` ) then Java compiler generates additional code section to display the stacktrace from local variable of type `Throwable`. That's because Java compiler is decomposing try with resources statement into separate tries - one for closing the resource and another for statements inside your `try`.

How is it displayed after decompilation - it depends on the decompiler you use.

Answer (score 1):

Author of CFR here - short answer - CFR's 'resugaring' isn't perfect ;)  (though the decompiled code is entirely correct, and valid.)

If you find something like this, feel free to submit a bug/improvement.

For what it's worth - the *ACTUAL* bytecode bears much less of a resemblance to the input - try using cfr with the arguments

> --tryresources false --decodefinally false

And you get the *unsugared* code, which is much closer to the actual bytecode.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String zipPath = "D:/test";
    try {
        ZipOutputStream zipOut;
        block11 : {
            zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipPath));
            Throwable throwable = null;
            try {
                String Hello2332 = "Hello";
                System.out.println("==============>" + Hello2332);
                if (zipOut == null) return;
                if (throwable == null) break block11;
            }
            catch (Throwable Hello2332) {
                try {
                    throwable = Hello2332;
                    throw Hello2332;
                }
                catch (Throwable throwable2) {
                    if (zipOut == null) throw throwable2;
                    if (throwable == null) {
                        zipOut.close();
                        throw throwable2;
                    }
                    try {
                        zipOut.close();
                        throw throwable2;
                    }
                    catch (Throwable throwable3) {
                        throwable.addSuppressed(throwable3);
                        throw throwable2;
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                zipOut.close();
                return;
            }
            catch (Throwable Hello2332) {
                throwable.addSuppressed(Hello2332);
                return;
            }
        }
        zipOut.close();
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this bug? @lab27

Comment: Eh, not a 'bug'; It was a 'could look slightly better' ;) The output was entirely correct but the extra try block was unnecessary.   I've fixed it on master.